# How do I use JQuery inside a constructor function inside a JS namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

OK, yesterday I asked about this but there was a stupid bug in my code so I ended up getting the answer to the wrong question.

I want to use JQuery inside a javascript constructor function, which sits inside a namespace:

```
var NS=NS||{};

NS.constructor=function()
{
    this.problem="doing my head in"
    this.solution="looking very messy"

    function useJQuery()
    {
        $(document).ready
        (
             function()
            {
                 $('body').html("I've written out the whole 'document ready function thing");
            }
         )
    }

    function usePlainJS()
    {
            return "Now I'm using plain JS";
    }

    function useJQueryAgain()
    {
        $(document).ready
        (
            function()
            {
                $('body').html("Now I've written out the 'document ready' thing AGAIN!");
            }
         )
    }
```

}

Is there a better way of doing this, without writing out the whole 'document ready' thing every time I want to use JQuery?

Comment: What is the *purpose* of those functions? That seems to be the most messy thing :|

Comment: Simplest solution: Include all your code at the end of `body` and don't worry about `document.ready` anymore. Alternative, initialize all your namespace stuff inside `document.ready`.

Comment: @user2864740 - the purpose of those functions is to demonstrate my question to you.

Comment: @DanLuba The code is nonsensical, especially since it doesn't show usage. This is why I asked for a/the *purpose* (which is not currently demonstrated).

Comment: @FelixKling - I tried initialising the namespace stuff inside the document.ready, but my variables came back as undefined due to scoping issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach one.** You can avoid repetitive `$(document).ready` blocks if you wrap function invocations themselves into `$(functionName)`. For example:

```
var NS = NS || {};

NS.constructor = function() {   
    this.problem = "doing my head in"
    this.solution = "looking very messy"

    // Here is an example of usage this function
    $(useJQuery);

    function useJQuery() {
        $('body').html("I've written out the whole 'document ready function thing");
    }

    function usePlainJS() {
        return "Now I'm using plain JS";
    }

    function useJQueryAgain() {
        $('body').html("Now I've written out the 'document ready' thing AGAIN!");
    }
};
```

**Approach two.** Put all your code before closing `</body>` tag, after the rest of the DOM contents. This way you don't have to worry about document ready, because by the moment script is executed HTML structure is already available.

Comment: Ah - I understand about the </body> thing, now. Thanks. That's what FelixKling was saying. Yeah - that makes sense. The code you wrote above looks much better than mine - I can't work out exactly what it's doing, though. Any chance you could walk me through that a little bit?

Comment: `$(functionName)` is the same as `$(document).ready(functionName)`. Which is the *same* as `functionName()` when `function functionName() { $(document).ready(function() { ... }) }`. Does it make sense?

Comment: It **almost** makes sense... what I don't understand is what the code `$(useJQuery)` is actually doing. It's not calling the function because it doesn't have `()`. When the `useJQuery()` function _is_ called and fetched from memory, how does the `$(useJQuery)` (which seems to be bypassed in a function call) manage to influence how the useJQuery function is executed?

Comment: If you pass a function into `$()` this is what happens: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/679536ee4b7a92ae64a5f58d90e9cc38c001e807/src/core/init.js#L100

Comment: Phew... I've been learning javascript and JQuery for about two weeks and that code is a bit difficult for me to understand... I'll figure  it out. Thanks for your help, man. I'm gonna mark this as answered because I have the 'how' I was looking for, even if I'm not grasping the 'why' just yet.

Comment: Basically if you pass a function into `$()` jQuery will put it into the functions array to be executed on DOMContentLoaded event (DOM ready). If this event has already fired, then the function will simply be executed immediately.

Comment: Thanks for spending your time on this. Let me try and get it straight... 1) an instance of the class is initiated. 2)it sits around in memory, waiting to be used. 3) if 10 minutes later, useJQuery is called by a script, the whole class is fetched from memory. 4) the whole class is parsed again in a procedural fashion. 5)if useJQuery is the function being called (rather than another function in the instance) then it is executed immediately (because the page loaded 10 minutes ago). 6) If another function from the class was being called, then useJQuery would not be executed. Is that how it goes?

Comment: I still feel like I'm missing something.